# Excel VBA set multiple cells to the same value

Tags: excel, vba, cell, assign, multiple-value

I want to set every eighth cell on one worksheet to the value of a cell in another worksheet. I wrote this here:

```
Sub xx()
    For i = 5 To 45 Step 8
        Set ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(i, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet7").Cells(13, 31).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

If I try to run it, it gives me a subscript out of range error.
*Sheet5* has also been named *Binomial Sheet*, do I have to reference this differently?
Are there other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Remove `Set` and make sure the sheet names are OK.

Comment: If the name of the sheet (not VBA object) is `Binomial Sheet` then you have to use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Binomial Sheet").Cells(...` or `Sheet5.Cells(...`

Answer (score 19):

This option of setting the same value for several cells was not yet mentioned:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1,B2,C3:D4").Value = "SomeValue"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to set the value of one cell to another in this way, you don't need to use the Set property - which is for objects not values.

Also ThisWorkbook refers to where the macro is held, but is not suited to calling in this way.

As such, I'd give: `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(i, 3).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet7").Cells(13, 31).Value`

a go, as this works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seemed to be that you had an `end if` without a corresponding `If` to start, and to assign a value for the range in sheet 5 you don't need to state `set` you can just assign the values directly like so:

```
Sub xx()
For i = 5 To 45 Step 8
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(i, 3).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet7").Cells(13, 31).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: A sentence or two of explanation would have gone a long way toward making this a much better answer.

Comment: A follow up question: It writes the value now, but it doesn't write the same value in each cell. Sometimes it writes 0 and sometimes 1 or 2, even though the cell from sheet7 reads 0

Comment: @Prot - tested this using a value in cell "AE13" in sheet7 and it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Worksheets have a [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx) and a [CodeName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx). Generally speaking, when the worksheets are first created, the two are visually the same but referenced differently. The worksheet's .Name can be changed; the .CodeName cannot be changed.

If *Sheet5* was renamed *Binomial Sheet* but *Sheet7* was not renamed, this is the difference in referencing them.

```
dim i as long
with activeworkbook
    for i = 5 To 45 step 8
        'using the worksheet .Name with the names as quoted strings
        .Sheets("Binomial Sheet").Cells(i, 3) = .Sheets("Sheet7").Cells(13, 31).Value
        'using the worksheet .CodeName directly
        Sheet5.Cells(i, 3) = Sheet7.Cells(13, 31).Value
    next i
end with
```

The .CodeName for Sheet5 did not change when its .Name was changed to *Binomial Sheet*. The.CodeNames for each worksheet (and its .Name in brackets) are listed within the VBE's **Project Explorer** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).

Comment: Nice explanation, but _the .CodeName cannot be changed_ is not true. You can change it in the properties window.

Comment: That was supposed to be a secret. ;)

Comment: @Jeeped, Good explanation.  Do you ever personally use the `Sheet` object as opposed to going through `Sheets(...)`?  I always thought the default names were awful in terms of descriptions... and you've got that issue about easily changing the name and breaking all your object references.

Comment: @Byron - Typically, I use worksheet names but that is the nature of the work I do. To a lesser extent I will use codenames and sometimes (rarely) index numbers. The latter when I specifically do *not* a finite worksheet queue reordered. It really depends on the situation. For demonstration purposes here, codenames are confusing to the beginner and I prefer to not have to explain every With/End With snippet. I already get enough of that with my use of 1E+99.