# Fill many cells in a row with one value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to fill 1299 cells in a row with the value 0530 using the following code:

```
Sub FillValues()

    Dim X As Integer

    For X = 2 To 1300

        Worksheets("Table1").Range("B" & X).Value = "'0530"

    Next X

End Sub
```

For some reason it doesn't work and I don't know why. The error is "Index beyond the valid range."

Comment: You need to either format the range as a string (e.g., with the `:` included), or you need to define it using `Cells`. You've got a strange mix of both going on. Also, you might have an extra apostrophe in your value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA set multiple cells to the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30638716/excel-vba-set-multiple-cells-to-the-same-value)

Answer (score 2):

Please try (no loop):

```
Worksheets("Table1").Range("B2:B1300").Value = "'0530"
```